# Django: Update a model attributre after a certain period of time

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a car reservation form. The form redirects to a view after saving. The view  **fetches the form id** i.e., an instance of my `Reservation` model, and then **selects the specific vehicle from the form's** `chosen_car` field, then, should **update that vehicle's** `available` **attribute to** `False`.

Now, a user books a car for a *fixed period of time*. When the time gets over, I want the `available` attribute of the specific vehicle instance in the `Vehicle` model to be set to `True`.

I tried to implement this using while loop in a view but it just isn't working. I want this process to be *somewhat automated*, i.e., for a vehicle instance the `available` attribute updates to `False` when that vehicle is reserved, and updates to `True` when the time gets over. This way it becomes available for other users to book.

```
# My Vehicle model:

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    car_no = models.CharField (max_length = 20, blank=False)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey (Car_model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    garage = models.ForeignKey (Garage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

# The Reservation model:

class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_from = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    date_to = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    time_from = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    time_to = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    garage = models.ForeignKey(Garage,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, verbose_name="Start from")
    destination=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, verbose_name="Where will you go")
    chosen_vehicle=models.CharField(max_length = 20, blank=False, default='')
    booking_time=models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
```

The view i've used to set the `Vehile` model's `available` attribute of each booked car to True or False:

```
def carDBconfigView(request, pk):
    this_form = Reservation.objects.get(pk = pk)
    the_car = this_form.chosen_vehicle
    v = Vehicle.objects.get(car_no = the_car)
    v.available = False
    v.save()
    to = this_form.date_to
    to_time = this_form.time_to

    #while datetime.date.today() > to and datetime.datetime.now().time() > to_time:  # tried this first
    while datetime.datetime.now().time() > to_time:
    while datetime.date.today() > to:
        c = Vehicle.objects.get(car_no = the_car)
        c.available = True
        c.save()
    return redirect('review')
```

The reservation form I have defined:

```
class NewReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Reservation
        exclude = ['user','chosen_vehicle','garage','booking_time']
```

How can I set the `available` attribute to `True` or `False` based on the set dates, without always manually setting each vehicle to `True` or `False`?

Comment: What I would suggest is to use `available` as property that checks if there any reservations with timerange that is `datetime.now()` in. But if you want to store it and change it after the time is passed you can use Celery. But I believe using property is much better for that case, for example if someone prolongs reservation and `time_to` is changed.

Comment: I have no prior experience with celery, but can I use it for this purpose? Then I gotta learn Celery.

Comment: You can learn Celery, but why don't you want to use it as property?

Comment: Can you please give an example for my scenario, I don't know about the property decorator either.

Comment: I added it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `from` and `to` to be `DateTmeField` and let `chosen_vehicle` be `ForeignKey` for a `Vehicle`:

```
class Reservation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    from = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    to = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=False)
    garage = models.ForeignKey(Garage,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, verbose_name="Start from")
    destination=models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, verbose_name="Where will you go")
    chosen_vehicle=models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reservations')
    booking_time=models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    car_no = models.CharField (max_length = 20, blank=False)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey (Car_model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    garage = models.ForeignKey (Garage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey (Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def available(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        # here we check if we have reservation that started before now and
        # will be finished after now
        reservations = self.reservations.filter(from__gte=now, to__lte=now)
        # exists() return boolean True or False
        return reservations.exists()
```

What you have when you apply this: you can check if a vehicle available now by property like:

```
my_vehicle = Vehicle.objects.get(...)
my_vehicle.available  # will return True or False
```

So every time when you check `my_vehicle.available` it will be calculated according to the current time and return the latest info.

Comment: reservations = self.reservations.filter(from__gte=now, to__lte=now); here, how the 'reservations' can be accessed? Or, is it 'Reservation'?

Comment: Because when I sey `chosen_vehicle` in `Reservation` model as `Foreign Key` I added `related_name=reservations` so of any vehicle object you can access all reservations connected with it by `my_vehicle.reservations.all()` Read more about `related_name` in docs.